# App for collecting (and categorizing) stuff from the web

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, web-browsing, productivity

I've looked high and low and I'm surprised I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for; it seems like such a common task.

I just want an iPhone app to **rapidly clip stuff from web pages**. My first priority is just to clip images (with source url and/or caption). But being able to do the same with bits of text, links, videos, etc would be nice.

**The way I imagine it working is:** I navigate on the web. I hold down an image or selection. Some "drop points" appear on the side for me to drag and drop it into. I can have as many drop points as I want and they can have names.

**More abstractly:** I just want a very gestural/natural way (i.e. doesn't require thinking or tapping) to grab stuff from web pages and put them into folders.

Comment: I think you are missing something in the complexity of css & html. You can't just 'clip a bit out of a web page' It just doesn't work like that. Grabbing a picture by comparison is trivial.

Comment: @Tetsujin good point but I know there are some good algorithms for doing this. Anyway, just being able to drag and drop images into folders would solve 90% of my problem

Comment: @Tetsujin "You can't just 'clip a bit out of a web page” - Evernote does exactly this. It’s "Web clipper” function is this. It can save a full webpage as a .webloc, locally. It can clip an image, it can clip a text selection. It’s fully integrated with iOS 8 and OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for something similar for a while now, though I am more interested in saving bits of text. So far, I've not found anything ideal, but there are two that I've come across that work pretty well.

[Pearltrees](http://www.pearltrees.com/) seems to be the best, particularly for pictures and entire websites. There is an ios app for it, and you can add a button for it on your share menu. Additionally, Pearltrees is online, and both Firefox and Chrome (and probably Safari) have an extension for it. Your Pearltrees account has folders, so you can sort what you have-- there is also a "dropshelf" where you can put things until you have time to sort them later. The downside is that all of your folders and items are public with the free account-- should you want to make any of them private, you need to upgrade to a paid version.

[Diigo](https://www.diigo.com/) seems to be a good way to save webpages and clips of text from a web browser. I have not explored it in detail, so I cannot speak as to its ability to save pictures. The filing system involves tags instead of files. I find this more difficult in some respects, but it may be to your liking. It also has a full version that requires payment, though you can do a lot with the free version.

If you've found anything else, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: could you also provide links...

Answer (score 0):

I am going to add my comment as an answer: The app you are looking for is [**Evernote**](https://evernote.com/).

Since the description you provide essentially matches Evernote’s purpose and capabilities, I see no reason to provide further detail.